# thymleaf concatenation within th:text is overwriting previous value

Tags: spring-boot, thymeleaf

I wanted to concatenate two string variable. The requirement is very simple depend on condition i just have to concatenate a static string "Out of office". However when it get rendered only "out of office" is getting displayed and not previous variable values like first and last name. any idea?

```
<option th:text="${assignee.getUserProfile().getFirstName() + ' ' + assignee.getUserProfile().getLastName() + assignee.getUserProfile().getOutOfOfficeApproval() != null? '(Out of office)':''}"/>
```

Comment: Add parenthesis around the statement. Currently the whole concatted String is used for the `!=` comparison. Also you might want to do this in your controller instead of your view and fill a boolean or the message in there.

Comment: @M.Deinum Can you please show me how to write that parenthesis around the statement which you are talking about?

Comment: Just wrap the last part in `()` that should do the trick, but as suggested I would move this logic to the controller instead of starting to program in HTML templates.

Answer (score 1):

Like this:

```
<option th:text="${assignee.getUserProfile().getFirstName() + ' ' + assignee.getUserProfile().getLastName() + (assignee.getUserProfile().getOutOfOfficeApproval() != null? '(Out of office)':'')}"/>
```

You can improve the formatting with th:with, inlining, and javabean formatting as well. Something like one of these:

```
<option th:with="profile=${assignee.userProfile}" th:text="${profile.firstName + ' ' + profile.lastName + (profile.outOfOfficeApproval != null? ' (Out of office)' : '')}">
```

or (w/Thymeleaf 3)

```
<option th:with="profile=${assignee.userProfile}">
    [[${profile.firstName + ' ' + profile.lastName}]]
    [[${profile.outOfOfficeApproval != null? '(Out of office)' : ''}]]
</option>
```